# How do I trace which file RSpec is loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I'm using Rails 3.0.1, RSpec-Rails 2.0.1 and Webrat 0.7.1.  I have the following test:

```
describe PagesController do
  describe "GET 'main'" do
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'main'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "My title")
    end
  end
end
```

The HTML of pages#main checks out: it contains My Title.  When I run rspec, it gives me a failure on this test, and says it expects to find the tag in the following line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

Since this is not the file stored at pages#main, I take it that rspec is, for some reason, loading the wrong page.  How do I solve this?  Or, failing a general solution, how can I get rspec to tell me which page it is trying to load, so that I can try to figure out why it is going to this other page?  Thanks.

Comment: I get two calls to "processing by PagesController#main as HTML" … one resulting in "rendering pages/main.html.erb" (as one would expect), and then another which results in nothing.  I'm not sure it gets me any closer to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell RSpec to render the views:

```
describe PagesController do
  render_views # Add this line to tell RSpec to render the views
  describe "GET 'main'" do
  .
  .
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to post log/test.log:

```
  Processing by PagesController#main as HTML
Rendered pages/main.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  Processing by PagesController#main as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

It looks to me like the first one results in a page being rendered - what is the second call for?

Comment: If you find the limits of comments too restrictive, then you should edit your question to include the information instead of posting it as an “answer”.